# Bootstrap delete row without refreshing page using modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

So far I can now delete the record using modal, but it just needs to go to the page delete-page. I want to delete the record with confirmation before deleting (using modal) and then delete the record without refreshing the page.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".btn-show-modal").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#dialog-example").modal('show');
        });

        $("#btn-delete").click(function(e) {
            $("#dialog-example").modal('hide');
        });
    });
</script>


<?php
    $stmt2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT project_code, description FROM tblprojects");
    $stmt2->execute();

    for($i=0; $row2 = $stmt2->fetch(); $i++){
        $project = $row2['project_code'];
        $desc = $row2['description'];
    ?>
    <tr class="record" id="record-">
        <td>
            <a href="project-detail.php?code=<?php echo $project; ?>">
                <?php echo $project; ?></a>
        </td>
        <td><?php echo $desc; ?></td>
        <td>
            <a href="update-project.php?code=<?php echo $project; ?>" title="Update record">
                <i class="icon-edit icon-white"></i>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="#"
               data-id="<?php echo $project; ?>"
               id="<?php echo $project; ?>"
               class="btn-show-modal" data-toggle="modal" title="Delete record">
                <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
            </a>
        </td>

        <div class="modal hide fade" id="dialog-example">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5>Confirm Delete</h5>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <p class="modaltext">Are you sure you want to delete this record?</p>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-info">No<a>
                        <a href="delete-project.php?code=<?php echo $project; ?>"
                           data-id="<?php echo $project; ?>"
                           class="btn btn-danger" id="btn-delete">Yes<a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Any ideas? Thank you for your help.

Comment: look at ajax: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @martincarlin87 Yes I tried the ajax part but it's not working for me? THe modal is not displaying

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#btn-delete").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get(this.href, function(){
        $("#dialog-example").modal('hide');
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't know how to pass the selected data to my ajax :(

Comment: so, `this.href` basically equals `delete-project.php?code=<?php echo $project; ?>"`. Have you confirmed that `delete-project.php?code=<number>` is working fine?

Answer (score 0):

I do this all in the time in my projects but didn't want to post it since the code might not mean anything to others (and it's fairly long) but this is what I do:

```
<!-- Delete Modal -->
<div id="delete_modal" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="-1">
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Delete</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
    <button id="delete_confirm" class="btn red btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Delete</button>
</div>
```

```
<!-- Submit Delete Modal -->
<div id="submit_delete_modal" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Deleting</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">
                <div class="alert alert-info">Deleting... <img src="/images/loading.gif" alt="Deleting..." /></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So that's the two modals I use, one for the confirmation and another to show that the item is actually being deleted.

This is the JS:

```
    $('.delete').click(function() {

        $('#delete_modal .modal-body div div').html('Are you sure you want to delete this row?');
    });

    // this is the delete button in the confirmation modal
    $('#delete_confirm').click(function() {

        $('#delete_modal').modal('hide');

        $('#submit_delete_modal').modal('show');

        $.ajax({           
            url: '/delete-page', 
            data: { id: id },
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,           
            success: function(data) {

                if (data === '1') {

                    // delete the row from the DOM
                    $('tr#record-' + id).fadeOut('slow').remove();

                    $('#submit_delete_modal .modal-body div div').html('<div class="alert alert-success"><i class="icon-ok-sign"></i> The row has been deleted</div>');

                } else {
                    $('#submit_delete_modal .modal-body div div').html('<div class="alert alert-error"><i class="icon-exclamation-sign"></i> Deletion failed, please refresh the page and try again</div>');
                }

            },
            error: function() {
                $('#submit_delete_modal .modal-body div div').html('<div class="alert alert-error"><i class="icon-exclamation-sign"></i> Deletion failed, please refresh the page and try again</div>');
            }   
        });

        return false;

    });
```

Just a pointer, looking at your `tr` markup, are you meaning to put the `id` from the database as part of the row id?

You have `<tr class="record" id="record-">` so every row has the same id, if you add the correct parameter there every row will have a unique id and the delete part in the ajax callback will work.

The only thing that remains is to get the id when something is clicked but I'm finding it hard to tell what link you are using to perform the delete.

It should be something like this:

```
    var id; // put this as the very first line of js, if it's in the global scope it can be accessed from anywhere, it's not best practise though.

    $(document).on('click', '.some_class_name', function() {

        id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id').split('-').pop();

        $('#delete_modal .modal-body').html('Are you sure that you want to remove this row?');
        $('#delete_modal').modal('show');

        // uncomment this to check you're getting the correct id and that it's not undefined etc
       // alert('id');

        return false;

    });
```

I've tried to make everything generically named to avoid stuff from my projecting bleeding in but I might have missed some things and made some errors when renaming elements etc.